# how to download any flash game from website to my PC?

Tags: flash

How can I download a Flash game from a website?

Answer (score 3):

I've developed a Chrome extension that enables you to download flash files or just open them in full screen in a single click.

The extension called Flash Master, here is the webstore link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flash-master/cacfnookefkldifaigjdedpophfjkjeh

Answer (score 2):

See [How To Download and Play Flash Games Offline](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-play-flash-games-offline/).

It describes downloading using the website [File2HD.com](http://file2hd.com/Default.aspx), then how to play using [FlashOffliner](http://flashoffliner.en.softonic.com/) (Windows only).